# groupby rolling agg custom function for portfolio beta

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, finance

Thanks for reading and in advance for any answers.

Beta is a measure of systematic risk of an investment portfolio. It is calculated by taking the covariance of that portfolios returns against the benchmark / market and dividing it by the variance of the market. I'd like to calc this on a rolling basis against many portfolios.

I have a df as follows

```
PERIOD,PORT1,PORT2,BM
201504,-0.004,-0.001,-0.013
201505,0.017,0.019,0.022
201506,-0.027,-0.037,-0.039
201507,0.026,0.033,0.017
201508,-0.045,-0.054,-0.081
201509,-0.033,-0.026,-0.032
201510,0.053,0.07,0.09
201511,0.03,0.032,0.038
201512,-0.05,-0.034,-0.044
201601,-0.016,-0.043,-0.057
201602,-0.007,-0.007,-0.011
201603,0.014,0.014,0.026
201604,0.003,0.001,0.01
201605,0.046,0.038,0.031
```

Except with many more columns like port1 and port2.

I would like to create a dataset with a rolling beta vs the BM column.

I created a similar rolling correlation dataset with

```
df.rolling(3).corr(df['BM'])
```

...which took every column in my large set and calced a correlation vs my BM column.

I tried to make a custom function for Beta but because it takes two arguments I am struggling. Below is my custom function and how I got it to work by feeding it two columns of returns.

```
    def beta(arr1,arr2):
    #ddof = 0 gives population covar. the 0 and 1 coordinates take the arr1 vs arr2 covar from the matrix
    return (np.cov(arr1,arr2,ddof=0)[0][1])/np.var(arr2)

    beta_test = beta(df['PORT1'],df['BM'])
```

So this helps me find the beta between two columns that I feed in... question is how to do this for my data above and data with many columns/portfolios? And then how to do it on a rolling basis? From what I saw above with the correlation, the below should be possible, to run each rolling 3 month data set in each column vs one specified column.

```
beta_data = df.rolling(3).agg(beta(df['BM']))
```

Any pointer in the right direction would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you can `set_index` the columns PERIOD and BM, `filter` the column with PORT in it (in case you have other columns you don't want to apply the `beta` function), then use `rolling.apply` like:

```
print (df.set_index(['PERIOD','BM']).filter(like='PORT')
         .rolling(3).apply(lambda x: beta(x, x.index.get_level_values(1)))
         .reset_index())
    PERIOD     BM     PORT1     PORT2
0   201504 -0.013       NaN       NaN
1   201505  0.022       NaN       NaN
2   201506 -0.039  0.714514  0.898613
3   201507  0.017  0.814734  1.055798
4   201508 -0.081  0.736486  0.907336
5   201509 -0.032  0.724490  0.887755
6   201510  0.090  0.598332  0.736964
7   201511  0.038  0.715848  0.789221
8   201512 -0.044  0.787248  0.778703
9   201601 -0.057  0.658877  0.794949
10  201602 -0.011  0.412270  0.789567
11  201603  0.026  0.354829  0.690573
12  201604  0.010  0.562924  0.558083
13  201605  0.031  1.716066  1.530471
```

Comment: This is very helpful thank you. It solved my issue. setting BM into the index and getting it inside the index then is what I was missing. Took me hours to get this far! help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
def getbetas(df, market, window = 45):
    """ given an unstacked pandas dataframe (columns instruments, rows
    dates), compute the rolling betas vs the market.
    """
    nmarket = market/market.rolling(window).var()
    thebetas = df.rolling(window).cov(other=nmarket)
    return thebetas
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer - it is late, I will check this tomorrow and approve if its good. It looks very elegant. Thanks again